# CSS - How to stop elements moving down?

Tags: html, css

really basic question. But how do I stop the elements from going down a row? How do I keep them in the same div adjacent to each other?

```
 .navcontainer {width: 1300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 130px; background-color:red;}
 .grid1{width: 33.33%; height: 130px;}
 .grid2{width: 33.33%; margin-left: 33.33%; height: 130px; background-color: blue;}
 .grid3{width: 33.33%; margin-left: 66.66%; height: 130px;  background-color: green;}
```

[Screenshot of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A5yh.png)

Comment: Show HTML too, please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use float.

```
 .navcontainer {width: 1300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 130px; background-color:red;}
 .grid1{width: 33.33%; height: 130px;float:left;}
 .grid2{width: 33.33%; float:left; height: 130px; background-color: blue;}
 .grid3{width: 33.33%; float:left; height: 130px;  background-color: green;}
```

OR display:inline-block;

```
.navcontainer {width: 1300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 130px; background-color:red;}
 .grid1{width: 33.33%; height: 130px;display: inline-block;}
 .grid2{width: 33.33%; display: inline-block; height: 130px; background-color: blue;}
 .grid3{width: 33.33%; display: inline-block; height: 130px;  background-color: green;}
```

Comment: Don't forget to do `clear: both;` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `float : right` in both of the boxes which you need to put in a single row.

Or you can use `position : relative / absolute; left : 0px;` and it will make your box to be at left most position.

Hope it helps